# Java Exception Handling to Check Primitive Types

Tags: java, exception, primitive

I have a GUI program that simulates a fuel station.

In the program, there are 3 input fields:

- itemName
- number of Units(or volume in L)
- and amount in pence (per unit or litre).

You can then chose to add the item by volume, or by units. The idea is that you can buy fuel and other items (such as food), with minimal input boxes.

I'm using exception handling to check the input is what I want it to be:

- An `int` value to add by units
- and a `double` value to add by volume.

My code so far recognises that a double has been entered where it wants an integer, and throws the error.

For example, the input of: `item Name: Chocolate, Amount(or Litres): 2.5, Price: 85` gives the error: `The code used looks like this`

```
if (e.getSource () == AddByNumOfUnits) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(NumOfUnitsField.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        SetErrorField("Input must be the appropriate type (real number for volume, integer for units)");
    }
```

However when adding by volume, I can't get the program to only accept `double` values, or anything that uses a decimal point. An `int` can be passed in and accepted as a `double` value, which I don't want. The code I'm using is very similar:

```
if (e.getSource() == AddByVolume) {
    try {
        double itemVolume = Double.parseDouble(NumOfUnitsField.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        SetErrorField("Input must be the appropriate type (real number for volume, integer for units)");
    }
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction of any way of solving this, that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Why would 5 not be accepted as a double? You want the user to enter 5.0? Why?

Comment: Basically when displaying data back to the user, I'm using the data type to append "Litres of ...". So when you say for example input "chocolate bars, amount: 2, price 85", you can still add by volume, which gives the output "2 Litres of Chocolate"

Comment: I don't see any relationship with this and the fact that you force the user to enter 5.0 instead of 5. It seems you're annoying the user for a bad reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It checks if the number contains a . char which would make it a double

```
try {
    if(!NumOfUnitsField.getText().contains(".")){
        throw new NumberFormatException("Not a double");
    }
    double itemVolume = Double.parseDouble(NumOfUnitsField.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
    SetErrorField("Input must be the appropriate type (real number for volume, integer for units)");
}
```

EDIT: combined with codeboxs answer a solution would be

```
try {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
    if(!p.matcher(NumOfUnitsField.getText()).matches()){
        throw new NumberFormatException("Not a double");
    }
    double itemVolume = Double.parseDouble(NumOfUnitsField.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
    SetErrorField("Input must be the appropriate type (real number for volume, integer for units)");
}
```

Comment: what if i enter `25.`

Comment: Then it would still not parse as an double in the next line

Comment: Thank you! This worked for now. Seems quite a simple solution which I've completely overlooked

Comment: npnp, having a boring lecture so nice to escape that for a second ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`Double.parseDouble()` will happily accept integer values, so you should probably try a regular expression instead. This checks that you have at least 1 digit before and after a decimal point:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
boolean isDecimalValue = p.matcher(NumOfUnitsField.getText()).matches();
```